# tooltip shows out of td element for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a requirement to show click percentage for each link available in HTML
template which is got from DB dynamically. I had tried to display click 
percentage for each anchor link adding them to `data-title` using jQuery but 
the issue is when I hover the link tooltip was displaying at out range. Can
someone helpme out to show tooltip only when I hover nearthe anchor
link? or please give me a better solution..
I have attached all sample code in below fiddler link  Please find the sample fiddle and code.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ywncLh3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var anchors = [];
   $(this).find("a").each(function() {
     anchors.push($(this));
   });

   for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
     var _ele = '100%'
     $(anchors[i]).attr('data-title', _ele);
   }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}
a[data-title]:hover:before {
  width: 55px;
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color- stop(0, #eeeeee), color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="1024" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="1024" class="wrapper">
        <table width="25%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="series">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a target="_blank" class="editorLinks tooltip" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
                  <div>
                    <img src="../../car_2series.jpg" width="90" height="44" alt="2 Series" border="0" style="display: block;">
                  </div>
                  <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 45px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 45px; color: #030000;
                                    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;">
                                    Car A</h3>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="25%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="series">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a target="_blank" class="editorLinks tooltip" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
                  <div>
                    <img src="../../../feb2015/car_4series.jpg" width="90" height="44" alt="4 Series" border="0" style="display: block;">
                  </div>
                  <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 45px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 45px; color: #030000;
                                    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;">
                                    Car B</h3>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table width="1024" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="1024" class="wrapper">
        <table width="25%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="series">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a target="_blank" class="editorLinks tooltip" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
                  <div>
                    <img src="../../car_6series.jpg" width="90" height="44" alt="6 Series" border="0" style="display: block;">
                  </div>
                  <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 45px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 45px; color: #030000;
                                    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;">
                                   Car B</h3>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width="25%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="series">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a target="_blank" class="editorLinks tooltip" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" data-title="1/100%">
                  <div>
                    <img src="../../../car_7series.jpg" width="90" height="44" alt="7 Series" border="0" style="display: block;">
                  </div>
                  <h3 style="margin: 15px 0 45px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 45px; color: #030000;
                                    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;">
                                    7 Series</h3>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your code here and not at some site.

Comment: Try to change your `a[data-title]:hover:before` to `a[data-title]:hover:after `. It should be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to `:after` to make sure it's z-index is always greater than it's parent.
use absolute positioning inside a relative parent to control position

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/6ywncLh3/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it answered me.. but  this answer is not answering when i  have added some more code in fiddler

Comment: Tell me or show me what you have added and I will have another look at it ,mate.

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing you mean the "Pre-Owned Vehicles" link, right?
sorry, i only appended the code onto the whole a tag for demonstration. I'd give those 4 Car `div`s a different class that you can select. Alternatively, you could use `.offset()` which is a jQuery function. This will allow you to set the tooltip position relative to an `a` tag